# Java Connector for dhtmlxGantt

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dhtmlx

I used dhtmlxgantt in my Java EE project, I downloaded the java connector and I copied this example from this link [Java Connector for dhtmlxGantt](http://forum.dhtmlx.com/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=32995)  but `mix()` and `enable_order()` are ignored by  `JsonGanttConnector`.Thanks.

Test_conector.java

```
import com.dhtmlx.connector.DBType;
import com.dhtmlx.connector.JSONGanttConnector;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import com.dhtmlx.connector.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class Test_conector extends ThreadSafeConnectorServlet {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
   Connection conn=null;
  try {
     Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance ();
     conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/parc","root","");
  } catch (Throwable e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }

  JSONGanttConnector gantt = new JSONGanttConnector(conn, DBType.MySQL);
  gantt.servlet(req, res);

   gantt.mix("open", "1");
   gantt.enable_order("sortorder");

  gantt.render_links("gantt_links", "id", "source,target,type");
  gantt.render_table("gantts", "id","text", "start_date,duration,progress,sortorder,parent");

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

.mix and .enable_order API is available in PHP version of connector only.

You can use beforeRender behavior to define `open` property for the data objects. There is no alternative for the `enable_order` API as far as I can see.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I define open property ? Is there any other solution without using Java Connector ?